Filter list on given attribute value
I query the datasource aws_identitystore_groups to get a list of all groups in AWS Identity Center :
data "aws_identitystore_groups" "this" {
  identity_store_id = local.identity_store_id
}

locals {
  all_groups            = data.aws_identitystore_groups.this
}

The output of local.all_groups looks like this :
output "debug" {
  value = local.all_groups
}


groups= [
  {
    description = "Group with ReadOnly access to my app dev env"
    display_name= "GROUP01"
    external_ids= [
      {
        id = "aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"
        issuer = "https://scim.aws.com/zzzzzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz"
      },
    ]
    group_id= "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
    identity_store_id = "d-yyyyyyyyyy"
  },
  {
    description = "Group with ReadOnly access to my app prod env"
    display_name= "GROUP02"
    external_ids= [
      {
        id = "bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb"
        issuer = "https://scim.aws.com/zzzzzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz"
      },
    ]
    group_id= "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222"
    identity_store_id = "d-yyyyyyyyyy"
  },
  {
    description = "Group with developer access to my app"
    display_name= "GROUP03"
    external_ids= [
      {
        id = "cccccccc-cccc-cccc-cccc-cccccccccccc"
        issuer = "https://scim.aws.com/zzzzzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz"
      },
    ]
    group_id= "33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333"
    identity_store_id = "d-yyyyyyyyyy"
  },
]

From the local.all_groups list i am trying to extract only the entry for display_name= "GROUP02"
Seems quite obvious, but i am banging my head on that.
I have tried :
my_group = [ for val in local.all_groups : val if val.display_name == "GROUP02" ]

│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on modules/sample/main.tf line 16, in locals:
│   16:   my_group = [ for val in local.all_groups : val if val.display_name == "GROUP02" ]
│ 
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "display_name" for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the list?


my_group = { for k, val in local.all_groups : k => val if val.display_name == "GROUP02" }

Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on modules/sample/main.tf line 16, in locals:
│   16:   my_group = { for k, val in local.all_groups : k => val if val.display_name == "GROUP02" }
│ 
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "display_name" for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the list?

Expected result :
groups= [
  {
    description = "Group with ReadOnly access to my app prod env"
    display_name= "GROUP02"
    external_ids= [
      {
        id = "bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb"
        issuer = "https://scim.aws.com/zzzzzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz"
      },
    ]
    group_id= "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222"
    identity_store_id = "d-yyyyyyyyyy"
  },
]

Could someone help on filtering this list ?

The expression in the error message refers to local.all_groups, but you haven't included the definition of that local value in your question. I suggest editing your question to include that definition so that readers can understand what the error message is referring to.

local.all_groups is the list i have provided. But well i have edited the question

Your updated code example has all_groups = data.aws_identitystore_groups.this which suggests that local.all_groups would be a single object, in which case your for expression would be iterating over the values of the attributes of that object. The list of groups returned by that data source would be all_groups = data.aws_identitystore_groups.this.groups, making it a list of objects that all have display_name attributes as your for expression expects.

If display_name is unique consider converting groups to a map with display_name as a key.
Then access the entry with display_name=GROUP02:
locals {
  groups = [
    {
      description  = "Group with ReadOnly access to my app dev env"
      display_name = "GROUP01"
      external_ids = [
        {
          id     = "aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"
          issuer = "https://scim.aws.com/zzzzzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz"
        },
      ]
      group_id          = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
      identity_store_id = "d-yyyyyyyyyy"
    },
    {
      description  = "Group with ReadOnly access to my app prod env"
      display_name = "GROUP02"
      external_ids = [
        {
          id     = "bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb"
          issuer = "https://scim.aws.com/zzzzzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz"
        },
      ]
      group_id          = "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222"
      identity_store_id = "d-yyyyyyyyyy"
    },
    {
      description  = "Group with developer access to my app"
      display_name = "GROUP03"
      external_ids = [
        {
          id     = "cccccccc-cccc-cccc-cccc-cccccccccccc"
          issuer = "https://scim.aws.com/zzzzzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz"
        },
      ]
      group_id          = "33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333"
      identity_store_id = "d-yyyyyyyyyy"
    },
  ]

  groups_map = { for group in local.groups : group.display_name => group }

  group2 = local.groups_map["GROUP02"]
}

output "group2" {
  value = local.group2
}

Running terraform plan:
Changes to Outputs:
  + group2 = {
      + description       = "Group with ReadOnly access to my app prod env"
      + display_name      = "GROUP02"
      + external_ids      = [
          + {
              + id     = "bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb"
              + issuer = "https://scim.aws.com/zzzzzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz"
            },
        ]
      + group_id          = "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222"
      + identity_store_id = "d-yyyyyyyyyy"
    }


This is actually working. Your answer pointed where i was wrong, now my initial approach using if in a for loop is also working

@user2196728 glad to know it was helpful :-)

Looking more carefully, it appears that datasource aws_identitystore_groups returns a map with two elements :

A list of groups
The identity store ID

data.aws_identitystore_groups.this = {
  groups = [ ... ]
  identity_store_id = "d-yyyyyyyyyy"
}

By targeting the groups attribute only then we can filter using the initial approach using if in a for loop :
locals {
  all_groups = data.aws_identitystore_groups.this.groups
  my_group   = [for val in local.all_groups : val if val.display_name == "GROUP02"]
}

